# How to disconnect all clients for a session in opentok?

Tags: node.js, opentok, tokbox

I am  trying to disconnect all clients from a session in opentok. i Know for this i have to call forceDisconnect() method of opentk sdk but the thing is forceDisconnect() method take connection object as a parameter. All clients should be disconnected when presenter leave the call.
Now what i tried till now when presenter leave the room i call get OT.listStreams() method to get all the streams and i am getting all the streams but the stream object doesn't have connection property. so i am not able to call forceDisconnect() method to remove all client. I am using nodejs opentok sdk. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

The best way to implement this functionality would be to utilize [signaling](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/signaling/js/). This will allow you to send a command to each client to `forceDisconnect` themselves.

For additional help, reach out in the [Vonage Community Slack](https://developer.nexmo.com/community/slack).